# How to preserve the order of fields when exporting a table from ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, attribute-table, export

ArcMap allows you to re-order fields in an attribute table, by dragging+dropping either within the layer's > Properties > Fields tab, or within the Table window.

However, the order of the fields doesn't seem to be honoured when exporting this table to a new table.

Is it possible to preserve the order of fields when exporting an attribute table?

Comment: How are you exporting the table? From the UI or geoprocessing tool?

Comment: @Hornbydd I'm exporting using the > Export option from the Attribute Table

Comment: I use ET Geowizards to do this.  I have a paid version but I believe this tool may be one of the free ones.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I do not believe there is a tool or function that allows you to export a table with reordered fields. If anyone knows better please enlighten me! I've always felt it has been a bit of a limitation that the geo-processing tools do not honour the reordered fields. Especially the conversion tools .

In the past I had attempted to create a tool that did it. The following Python code can be used to re-order fields in a table by creating a new table with the fields re-ordered. In this example output (the new table) is sent to an IN_MEMORY workspace.

```py
inputTable = "ABC" # This is a table loaded into ArcMap
outputTable = "XYZ"

# Get field mappings of Input Table
fieldMappings = arcpy.FieldMappings()
fieldMappings.addTable(inputTable)

# Create an empty FieldMappings Object
newFieldMappings = arcpy.FieldMappings()

# Add fields in desired order. Note field index must be known
newFieldMappings.addFieldMap(fieldMappings.getFieldMap(3))
newFieldMappings.addFieldMap(fieldMappings.getFieldMap(0))
newFieldMappings.addFieldMap(fieldMappings.getFieldMap(2))
newFieldMappings.addFieldMap(fieldMappings.getFieldMap(1))

# Create Table
arcpy.TableToTable_conversion(inputTable, "IN_MEMORY", outputTable, None, newFieldMappings)
```

Dan Patterson recently created an interesting [blog page](https://geonet.esri.com/blogs/dan_patterson/2014/09/28/hidden-gemsworking-with-shapefiles-and-structured-arrays) on geonet showing how numpy can be used to do clever things with a FeatureClass. This could be another way one could  alter the field order.

But ideally ESRI should make their tools aware of field order...